# Include Views output in href

Tags: views, navigation

I am trying to create a custom button in Drupal 7.  The link which the href should be equal to is dependent on the context such as the current UID.

I have created a view which normally has a plain text output as [title].

I want to use that text output as part of a link field such as

```
http://my-site.com/page/title
```

so I had written the code for the above link as such:

```
<a href="http://my-site.com/page/<?php $block = module_invoke('views', 'block_view', 'profile3-block_4'); print render($block[content]); ?>">LINK TEXT</a>
```

however the output seems as if it is placing part of a views div tag in the link instead. I tried stripping all html from the views block but no success.  Anyone got ideas? Could it be an improper use of quotes?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$block = module_invoke('views', 'block_view', 'profile3-block_4'); 
$url = render($block[content]);
Assume your Output will be <div>TITLE</div>
then use **$url =  strip_tags($url);**
<a href="http://my-site.com/page/".$url>LINK TEXT</a>
It will be better to use **l()**
l(t('Link text'), 'http://my-site.com/page/'.$url);
```

If you are still facing issue request you to provide block html output.

Answer (score 0):

`print render($block[content]);` returns a lot of tags. It simply cannot be a valid part of URL string. Also, be sure to avoid `module_invoke` in tpl files if feasible.

Answer (score 0):

If the url is one of the fields returned in the view query then you could access the raw data of the url by calling [views_get_view_result($name, $display_id)](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7).

If it returns a uri then you may need to pass it though [file_create_url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) to get a url.

If the row returns a nid then the url might be generated via something like [drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . $nid)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7) (adapt as required for taxonomy terms, users, etc).

Comment: THank you .  I like your comment best. I will give this a try and get back to you

Comment: I assume that $name is the system field name? and $display_id is the block or page delta?

Comment: $name is the machine name of the entire view and $display_id is the machine name of the individual display within the view.  An easy way to find these is to go to the edit page of the view and look at the url.  It should be either "/admin/structure/views/view/VIEW_NAME/edit/DISPLAY_ID" or "admin/structure/views/view/VIEW_NAME", where VIEW_NAME will be replaced with the value you need for $name and DISPLAY_ID will be the replaced with the value you need for $display_id.  If it is the shorter version of the path and there is no $display_id then just call views_get_view_result($name).